# Why the output is 01122?

Tags: javascript, html

If we concatenate string and integers in Javascript the output must be the string part and then other numbers will be printed as string also, but in this it printed the zero then the number counted as integers not string and result the sum.

What is happening here?

```js
var x = document.getElementById("1");
x.innerHTML += 1111 + 11;
```

```html
<p id="1">0</p>
```

I expect the output of `01122` to be `0111111` or `1122`

Answer (score 3):

You are concatenating to a string the sum of 1111 and 11 (=1122).

Javascript will first evaluate the sum, then convert it to a string for concatenation, since you are asking to add it to the end of a string (`+=`).

If you want to get `0111111`:

```
x.innerHTML += '' + 1111 + 11;
```

If you want to get `1122`:

```
x.innerHTML = +x.innerHTML + 1111 + 11;
```